# Loop over folder structure and extract elements from all xml files

Tags: python, xml, pandas, loops

I´m quite new with coding and have a problem with the following:

I need to extract a specific element from xml files. I managed to write the code for doing that with one file. Now I need to do that with all xml files, which are separated in several folders and subfolders. The folder structure is here:

C:\uni\thesis\dataset\ --> and there I have three folders (80, 90, 00) that are again each divided in subfolders (1987, 1988, 1989 and the same for 90 and 00). In each of these subfolders are again each 12 folders (01, 02, 03,...) and each of these again has between 28 and 31 folders where the xmls are (approx. 200 files each).
Now this is a very complex structure and I need to loop over all the folders to get to all xmls and extract the one element.

I have absolutely no idea how to manage that and would be happy if someone could help!

Comment: you need to recursivly look through all the dirs for each element you find in a dir check if its a dir or an xml file, if its a dir, go into it and start again, do this until you get to a dir that has no other dirs, process all the files then move back up and get the next dir

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.walk()` to achieve that

```
import os

dir = "/your_dir"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for name in files:
        filepath = root + os.sep + name
        if filepath.endswith(".xml"):
            //do your function
```